# Joining tables with itself SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to generate a table in SQL BigQuery of the folder structure of our server. I want a table which contains the name of the file and which folder is it in. The issue is that information of which folder it belongs as well as which subfolders it contains is in the same table and it can have an arbitrary number of folder levels, like so:

```
folder_id Name parent_folder_id
123       One    321
321       root_1  null
456       two     321
789       Three   456
```

I want a table like this:

```
parent_folder_name name
root_1              One
'root'             root_1
root_1              two
two                 three
```

but i can't get the first step right, namely to join each file and folder with its parent.
I've work in an adaptation of an answer I saw in SO like this:
SELECT
b.name,
CASE when b.parent_project_id is null then 'root'
ELSE b.parent_project_id END as parent_folder_name , a.name, a.owner_id FROM data a
JOIN  data b
on b.parent_project_id = a.id

It actually return good results, but about 60% of all registries when missing and i can't see why
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get just the parent, use a `left join`, presumably:

```
SELECT d.name,
       (CASE WHEN dp.parent_project_id is null THEN 'root' ELSE dp.name END) as parent_folder_name,
       dp.name as parent_folder_name, d.name, d.owner_id
FROM data d1 LEFT JOIN
     data dp
     ON d.parent_project_id = dp.id;
```

You can add additional `LEFT JOIN`s to go higher in the hierarchy.  Unfortunately, BigQuery does not support recursive CTEs, so a single query cannot be used to traverse the entire hierarchy.  Happily, BigQuery does support scripting, so you can express such a traversal using the scripting language.

Comment: Perfect!! had to replace the coalesce for the following : case when dp.parent_project_id is null then 'root'
       else dp.name end as parent_folder_name,